# Tanstack/react-query doesn't work in my vercel app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, devtools, tanstackreact-query

the packages and the problem..

```
"@tanstack/react-query": "^5.14.2",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.14.2",

"next": "^13.5.6",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
```

QueryProvider.js

```
"use client";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'; // downgrading react and next version raise peer dependency errors

export default function QueryClientProviderComponent ({ children }) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 5  // added the staleTime for queries globally
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      {children}
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen/>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

layout.js

```
import './globals.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

import QueryClientProviderComponent from "./components/QueryClientProvider";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'abc',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <QueryClientProviderComponent>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          {children}
          <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
        </body>
      </html>
    </QueryClientProviderComponent>
  )
}
```

The problem I am facing is the devtools appear correctly, only when `npm run dev` is run.

How can i display it in vercel-deployed app and staging env.

Any help is appreciated.

I tried following the official docs at
https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/devtools - devtools appear correctly, only when `npm run dev` is run and not on vercel

1. I tried modifying the code to the one above by just passing ReactQueryDevTools.
2. tried downgrading my dependencies but internally the app crashed.
3. modified the structure to

```
....
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <QueryClientProviderComponent>
          {children}
          <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
        </QueryClientProviderComponent>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

4. tried safari instead of chrome
5. followed the structure outlined [here](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/3296)
6. also, when i try window.toggleDevTools in console in gives undefined

Comment: What happened when you tried this step? https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/devtools#devtools-in-production

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar devtools appeared only in local (npm run dev)..not on local build and vercel deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it.

**Method 1 (following the official doc):** [Link](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/devtools#devtools-in-production)

Step 1: Add the necessary changes described as the per official doc in your QueryProvider file

QueryProvider.js

```
'use client';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'; // downgrading react and next version raise peer dependency errors
import { Suspense, lazy, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ReactQueryDevtoolsProduction = lazy(() =>
  import('@tanstack/react-query-devtools/build/modern/production.js').then(
    (d) => ({
      default: d.ReactQueryDevtools,
    }),
  ),
);

export default function QueryClientProviderComponent({ children }) {
  const [showDevtools, setShowDevtools] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    window.toggleDevtools = () => setShowDevtools((old) => !old);
  }, []);

  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 5, // added the staleTime for queries globally
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      {children}
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
      {showDevtools && (
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <ReactQueryDevtoolsProduction />
        </Suspense>
      )}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

In layout file, wrap it inside body
layout.js

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <QueryClientProviderComponent>{children}</QueryClientProviderComponent>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

This adds a function called `toggleDevtools` in your window.

Step 2: Downloading devtools

Open the Console of the tab in which you opened the website. Paste `window.toggleDevtools()` and hit Enter.

This will start the devtools.

**Method 2: Download by default**

If you noticed in Method 1, the initial value of showDevtools is false due to which you have to manually hit the toggleDevtools method. In case you want to avoid it then change

`const [showDevtools, setShowDevtools] = useState(false);`

To

`const [showDevtools, setShowDevtools] = useState(true);`

This will make sure that you don't have to manually call window.toggleDevTools()

Comment: my current code implementation is by method 2. still no luck... 
thanks

Comment: Can you create a mini repo for it to reproduce? @KunalBambardekar

Comment: I don't think that would be possible @BhaveshParvatkar
but it's a traditional nextjs appwith tanstack/react-query
when i run window.toggleDevTools in method 1 it crashes the DOM and method 2 has no effect.

Comment: Try changing the code in layout.js. I added it in Method 1. @KunalBambardekar

Comment: Dont add <ReactQueryDevtools /> in layout file. Just wrap it with your QueryProvider file that does the rest of the thing

Comment: Thanks @BhaveshParvatkar it worked. I was importing the <ReactQueryDevtools />  package twice as I thought QueryProvider wasn't working.

Comment: i noticed in the prod build of my app, even though if i have staleTime and cachetime of 5 mins and 2 mins respectively, the api is always "fetching" but surprisingly there is an api request only after 2 mins. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide more context on what you want to achieve? For the question regarding why it is getting called after 2 minutes, may be because a fresh instance of the hook is getting created which triggers the API call. You can read more [here](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/caching) and [here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#the-defaults-explained) @KunalBambardekar

Comment: Understood @BhaveshParvatkar. there are some behaviour changes in the development vs production build tbh.